# zsh function to export multiple variables from clipboard clipboard

Tags: shell, zsh, environment-variables

I want to be able to take the contents of the clipbard and evaluate it in zsh without showing the contents of the clipboard

```
export FOO=BAR
export BAR=BIZ
export BAZ=FOO
```

I've tried

```
function aws-eval-clipboard {
    eval | $(pbpaste)
}
```

I feel that's close? but I get

```
zsh: no such file or directory: export
```

I'm totally opening to using other commands that may even have to be installed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would rather be:

```
eval -- "$(pbpaste)"
```

or:

```
pbpaste | source /dev/stdin
```

`eval` evaluates the shell code resulting of the concatenation with spaces of its arguments. So here we take the output of `pbpaste` with `$(...)` command substitution, quoted so that it is not split and pass it as one argument to `eval` (preceded with `--` that marks the end of options in case that argument starts with `-`).

`source` evaluates the shell code stored in the file passed as its first argument. With `source /dev/stdin`, we tell it to evaluate the code it can read on its standard input, which here is a pipe with `pbpaste`'s output at the other end.

In `eval | $(pbpaste)`, you're running two commands connected by a pipe. The first one is `eval` without arguments, so it evaluates nothing, and so prints nothing to the pipe. The second one is constructed by taking the output of `pbpaste`, splitting it on `$IFS` and the resulting words making a simple command.

With the code you showed, that would result in the `export` command being run with  `FOO=BAR`, `export`, `BAR=BIZ`, `export`, `BAZ=FOO` as arguments, so should work in that case (would export those `FOO`, `BAR`, `BAZ` variables, but also the `export` variable). The error you get cannot be explained with that particular input.